# How to put a btn(in top menu bar) specific img of a page?

Tags: html, css

Let me explain..

I have a top menu bar in a ul and in each li, theres is a div tag inside a a tag. Each of my div tag has a background-image. When you hover your mouse on it, it changes. Here's my question :

How can I, for example, put my first li img like if it was on hover if the user is on the first page. And, how to always put it like if it was on hover for my second button when the user is on the second page? I think it can be achieve with php but I really can't remember!! I looked around and no answer so far. Thanks guys!

HTML :

```
<div id="topmenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.php"><div id="accueil"></div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php"><div id="contact"></div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="inventaire.php"><div id="inventaire"></div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="demande.php"><div id="demande"></div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="moncompte.php"><div id="moncompte"></div></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

My css :

```
#accueil {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -180px 0;
width:129px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#accueil:hover {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -1px 0;
width:129px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#contact {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -180px -33px;
width:101px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#contact:hover {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -16px -33px;
width:101px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#inventaire {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -180px -66px;
width:111px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#inventaire:hover {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -10px -66px;
width:111px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#demande {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -180px -99px;
width:175px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#demande {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -180px -99px;
width:175px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#demande:hover {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -1px -99px;
width:175px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#moncompte {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -180px -132px;
width:137px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

#moncompte:hover {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -1px -132px;
width:137px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you ask, it's simple. Add some class to indicate the current page.

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li> <div /> </li>
    <li> <div /> </li>
    <li> <div class="ActivePage" /> </li>
</ul>
```

And then css something like this (this is simplefied, you have to puzzle it in your code):

```
div{
    background: url('image.jpeg') no-repeat top left;
}
div:hover, div.ActivePage{
    background-position: bottom left;
}
```

---

Edit based on comment TS:

If you have php at your side, add a comment to your items:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">     <div class="<!-- ACTIVE_index -->" id="accueil"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">   <div class="<!-- ACTIVE_contact -->"id="contact"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="inventaire.php"><div class="<!-- ACTIVE_inventaire -->"id="inventaire"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="demande.php">   <div class="<!-- ACTIVE_demande -->"id="demande"></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="moncompte.php"> <div class="<!-- ACTIVE_moncompte -->"id="moncompte"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, make sure that index.php knows what page you are on before you include header.php. Let's say `$page = 'contact';`

In your header.php you do the following two lines:

```
$template = str_replace("<!-- ACTIVE_".$page." -->", 'ActivePage', $template); give the selected on the class

$template = preg_replace(/"<!-- ACTIVE_.*? -->", '', $template); // cleanup other comments
```

And now you have a flexible page indicator code :) This will make more sense what you start pulling the items from a database, or automate it some way

Comment: The problem is my header is in a header.php. So in my index.php, there's a php tag include header.php. So my header.php is the same for every page. It won't work in this case..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't rocket science man. You should probably think out of the box a bit more before turning to the community.

Here goes anyways...

Add a `.current-page` CSS class to the hover rule and append it to the element when it is the current page....

```
#contact:hover, #contact.current-page {
background:url('../images/top_menu.png') no-repeat -16px -33px;
width:101px;
height:31px;
float:left;
}

<ul>
       <li><a href="index.php"><div id="accueil"></div></a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.php" class="current-page"><div id="contact"></div></a></li>
       <li><a href="inventaire.php"><div id="inventaire"></div></a></li>
       <li><a href="demande.php"><div id="demande"></div></a></li>
       <li><a href="moncompte.php"><div id="moncompte"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem is my header is in a header.php. So in my index.php, there's a php tag include header.php. So my header.php is the same for every page. It won't work in this case..

Comment: I can't see why not.. you can look at the URL of the current request to get which one you want to show... `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']`

Comment: That was exactly what I was doing right now! Thanks a lot!